# How to create synthetic window events in C# (windows forms)

Tags: c#, .net

In some applications I need to create synthetic window events (e.g. click, keypress, mouse over...) and send them to arbitrary objects (buttons, labes, textboxes...). For many reasons, I can't add custom handlers to the destinations, I am forced to use existing event handlers and send fake window events to specific elements. The only way I have found is by invoking native Win32 API (SendMessage, PostMessage...) applied to underlying native window handles, but I don't like it because of portability issues (in particular, I can't use it on mono). I would prefer a "C#-only" solution. Is it possible? How can I do it in C# (.NET framework 4, in particular)?

Comment: No, that's what it takes.  There's no hope of portability, something as basic as a window handle is strongly tied to the platform.  Rather than hard-coding the messages, do look at System.Windows.Automation to take advantage of the UI Automation abstraction layer.  Use the Inspect.exe SDK tool to see what is supported by the target app.

Comment: Indeed I don't want to deal with window handles. My hope was to have something like "myButton.Invoke(new ClickEvent())". But I see that there is nothing like this in C#. I'll study Automation. Thank you.

Comment: There's a bit of confusion on what events mean, what a `Windows Event` is (completely unrelated) and what Windows *messages* are, which is what SendMessage and PostMessage do. None of these is used in desktop automation, which is what you probably mean by "automation". Applications that support real automation have APIs. Most Office applications have APIs for example and don't need messages or working with controls. Windows *messages* were only used in the late 1990s to "automate" desktop applications. This isn't used for almost 20 years

Comment: Since the 2000s, first through Windows Accessiblity APIs and then [UI Automation APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview) you can read the contents of an application's screen and interact with it. The GUI elements are owned and controlled by the OS itself, so any solution is highly OS-specific. It's the OS that tells you what's on the screen, what controls are there, what you can do with them. `System.Windows.Automation` is how you access the Automation API in .NET

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/invoke-a-control-using-ui-automation

Comment: Parhaps too late, but I want to clarify my question: my goal is to send synthetic events from INSIDE the same application. I can modify the code, but the code is not mine, and it's complex and intricated enough to induce me not to modify its internals. I'd prefer to add some "peripheric" hack to change its behaviour slightly, and preserve the core logic. I know I should avoid hacks and make changes "in the right place", but I'm short of time.